# StartupUri not recognized in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I have a MainPage in UWP like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private MainViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new MainViewModel(new MyDataService());
        DataContext = _viewModel;
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.Load();
    }
}
```

My window app started and run with no issue.

Now, I would like to pass the MainViewModel as a parameter to the MainPage.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private MainViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainPage(MainViewWindow mvw)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = mvw;
        DataContext = _viewModel;
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.Load();
    }
}
```

How do I initialize and pass the parameter to `MainPage`? Universal Windows Does not seem to recognize `StartupUri` in `App.xaml` like WPF.

Comment: You can handle [OnLaunched](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_OnLaunched_Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_LaunchActivatedEventArgs_) event to init your main viewmodel and navigate to main page. Another option is to use MVVM framework, which supports UWP and injection of viewmodel dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, a `Page` needs to have a parameterless constructor. The reason for this is that the `Frame.Navigate` method takes just a `Type` of the page as a parameter, and handles its instantiation. This is unfortunate and there are plans to improve this for future versions of WinUI (it is even one of the reasons Prism had to drop support for UWP in newer versions).

For now, you need to keep the constructor parameterless and inject the services after the constructor completes.

If you need to pass just simple parameter, you can use the `Frame.Navigate(Type, object)` method. The second parameter is, well, your parameter, which you can then retrieve when you override the `Page.OnNavigatedTo` method. Beware that the parameter type needs to be a simple type only (`string`, `int`, etc.) as it needs to be serialized automatically in the `Frame`'s navigation stack when the app is suspended. You can turn more complex parameters using JSON string if necessary.

Many MVVM frameworks can do most of this heavy lifting for you - MvvmCross for example. This has a very nice setup with a built-in IoC provider that does a lot of work for you, including managing view model lifetime and matching views and view models by naming convention.

Comment: Ah! Thank you Martin!! I am new to UWP and your explanation helps! It is quite a learning curve from WPF!

Comment: Glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!